# @font-face embeded in aspx file not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, iis, fonts

I am trying to use some interesting font in my website. But somehow the fonts aren't being loaded or not working for some reason .

I have a master page wherein 2 `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` tags are present. One in the head section for similar use like using external fonts , and another `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` in the body section.

I have tried two things :

**1)** One giving the url of the fonts stored on my visual studio.

**2)** Other giving the url of my file system.

Here is my HTML file :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <style>
        @font-face{
            font-family:Junction;
            src : url("http:localhost:63183/fonts/Junction.otf") format('opentype');
        }
        @font-face{
            font-family:chunkfive;
            font-weight:bold;
            src : url("f:\practicals7th sem\project docs\templates\temp1\chunkfive.otf") format('opentype');
        }

    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is my body section content :

```
<div style="text-align: center; font-family:'Junction.otf' ; font-size: 20px; color: #db2828">
                            <%# Eval("Name") %>
```

[image: Could find one <code>404</code> error but for a different bootstrap file.]

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the MimeTypes within IIS:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

You can then use relative paths to the fonts i.e.

```
 @font-face{
            font-family:Junction;
            src : url("/fonts/Junction.otf") format('opentype');
        }
        @font-face{
            font-family:chunkfive;
            font-weight:bold;
            src : url("/fonts/chunkfive.otf") format('opentype');
        }
```

Comment: adding this caused my rendered HTML to look like a skeleton . I dont know why but this did not work.

Comment: Have you got the files in a `/fonts` folder? Do you get 404's?

Comment: Yes i have got a `/Fonts` folder in my visual studio's `Server Explorer`. And where should i expect 404 ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Update the mime types. Re-try please.

Comment: Please check the screen capture i added.

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top